# How to use WindowMetrics after deprecation of Display.getRealSize() Display.getRealMetrics() methods?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, android-12

In Android 12 google continuing to recommend using WindowMetrics, and are deprecating these methods:

Display.getRealSize()
Display.getRealMetrics()

How to convert this code for Android 12 Migration

```
 val display: Display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
 val size = Point()
 display.getRealSize(size)

 val display: Display = activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay
 val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
 display.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val wm = fragmentActivity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val width: Int
val height: Int
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
 val windowMetrics = wm.currentWindowMetrics
 val windowInsets: WindowInsets = windowMetrics.windowInsets

 val insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(
      WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() or 
 WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout())
 val insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left
 val insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom

 val b = windowMetrics.bounds
 width = b.width() - insetsWidth
 height = b.height() - insetsHeight
} else {
 val size = Point()
 val display = wm.defaultDisplay // deprecated in API 30
 display?.getSize(size) // deprecated in API 30
 width = size.x
 height = size.y
}
```